# Task not in a faulted state when an exception is thrown

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

I can't seem to figure out why my task is not in a faulted state when an exception is thrown in the following sample (assume engine.Send(...) throws an exception):

```
       var receiverTask = new Task<Task>(async () => {
            result = await Task.FromResult(engine.Send(someObject));
        });
        receiverTask.Start();
        receiverTask.Wait();
```

if I do `receiverTask.IsFaulted` after the `receiverTask.Wait()` it returns false instead of true as I would expect.

I have been reading that I need to use something like the following construct:

```
receiverTask.ContinueWith(t => { /* error handling */ },
    TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
```

But I can't seem to figure out how to integrate this into the sample code. Do I call this before the Start()? before the Wait()?

I would like the calling program to somehow be aware that the receiverTask has thrown an exception and failed. Any pointers?

Comment: ContinueWith actually calls the Start and Wait methods in the background so you can remove both these calls and replace them with the continuewith method.

Comment: Check receiverTask.Result.IsFaulted. That task failed, not receiverTask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I correctly understand this context, you could leave out the `.Start()` and use `.Wait()` somewhat differently.

(I don't know what your `engine.Send(someObject)` method is, so I have to assume.)

Let's say your method returns a bool (it doesn't matter, but just to write something down.

If it is synchronous, the returned Task could be:

```
 Task<bool> receiverTask = Task<bool>.Run(async () =>
            await Task<bool>.FromResult(engine.Send(someObject)));
```

or

```
 Task<bool> receiverTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(async delegate
 {
    bool _result = await Task<bool>.FromResult(engine.Send(someObject));
    return _result;
 }, TaskScheduler.Default).Unwrap();
```

If it is asynchronous, the returned Task could be:

```
 Task<bool> receiverTask = Task.Run(async () =>
            await engine.Send(someObject));
```

or

```
 Task<bool> receiverTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(async delegate
 {
    bool _result = await engine.Send(someObject);
    return _result;
 }, TaskScheduler.Current).Unwrap<bool>();
```

(However, all these are blocking if there's no other async/await declaration).

Once your Task is scheduled, some Continuation condition can be defined to evaluate its status.
If the Task is in some faulty status (canceled, aborted etc.) its `.IsCompleted` property reports `true`, but the `.Status` property is not `TaskStatus.RanToCompletion`.

```
 receiverTask.ContinueWith(t =>
 {
    //Continue on faulted
    Console.WriteLine(receiverTask.GetAwaiter().IsCompleted);
    if (receiverTask.IsFaulted)
       Console.WriteLine(receiverTask.Exception.InnerExceptions[0].Message);
 }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted).Wait(0);

 receiverTask.ContinueWith(t =>
 {
    //Continue on canceled
    Console.WriteLine(receiverTask.GetAwaiter().IsCompleted);
    if (receiverTask.IsCanceled)
       Console.WriteLine(receiverTask.Exception.InnerExceptions[0].Message);
 }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnCanceled).Wait(0);

 receiverTask.ContinueWith(t =>
 {
    //Standard behaviour
    Console.WriteLine(receiverTask.GetAwaiter().IsCompleted);
    Console.WriteLine(receiverTask.Status.ToString());
 }, TaskContinuationOptions.None).Wait();

 //This writes only if no errors have been raised
 if (receiverTask.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
    Console.WriteLine("Completed: {0}  Result: {1}", receiverTask.GetAwaiter().IsCompleted, receiverTask.Result);
```

But you might also use a Try/Catch block:

```
 try
 {
    receiverTask.Wait();

    if (receiverTask.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
       Console.WriteLine("Completed: {0}  Result: {1}", receiverTask.GetAwaiter().IsCompleted, receiverTask.Result);
 }
 catch (Exception)
 {
    receiverTask.ContinueWith(t =>
    {
       //With continuation
       if (receiverTask.IsFaulted)
          Console.WriteLine(receiverTask.Exception.InnerExceptions[0].Message);
    }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);

       //or without
       //if (receiverTask.IsCanceled)
       //Console.WriteLine(receiverTask.Exception.InnerExceptions[0].Message);
 }
```