# How do I use continueWith to continue a task with another task?

Tags: vb.net

```
    Dim listOfTask = New List(Of Task)
    For Each account In uniqueAccounts().Values
        Dim newtask = account.conditionalInitializeAsync()
        Dim nexttask = account.getPairsPriceStepAsync()
        listOfTask.Add(newtask)
        listOfTask.Add(nexttask)
        Dim nexttaskaftenewtask = newtask.ContinueWith(nexttask) 'compiler warning
    Next
```

Instead of list

```
        listOfTask.Add(newtask)
        listOfTask.Add(nexttask)
```

I want to do

```
        listOfTask.Add(nexttaskaftenewtask )
```

How do I do so?

Comment: [Task not in a faulted state when an exception is thrown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47726080/7444103).

Comment: Don't use `ContinueWith()`, possibly. [Processing Sequences of Asynchronous Operations with Tasks](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/processing-sequences-of-asynchronous-operations-with-tasks/), [Dataflow (Task Parallel Library)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library).

Answer (score 1):

I can compile the following without error or warning. Hope this helps.

```
 Dim nexttaskaftenewtask = newtask.ContinueWith(New Action(Of Task)(Function() nexttask))
```

Comment: Please specify do you receive an error or a warning? What kind? Please specify.

Comment: @DarkoMartinovic no I do not receive an error or warning, that is what I said.

Comment: Before I try can anyone tell me a bit about how this really work. Action (of a task) is a sub that accepts a Task argument right. You are feeding it with a function that returns a task. How does that work?

Comment: It works. I am confused why.