# Why a thrown exception from Task is treates as Canceled?

Tags: c#

Why a thrown exception from Task is treated as Canceled (even though I didn't press 'x' to cancel it) and not as Faulted?
The output of the below code is:

```
Press 'x' to cancel
Job has been canceled
Task has been canceled
Press Enter to exit
```

**CODE**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {   
            var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
            var cancellationToken = cancellationTokenSource.Token;

            var jobTask = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                while (true)
                {
                    if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                    Thread.Sleep(2000);

                    if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                    throw new Exception("Test Exception");
                }

            }, cancellationToken)
            .ContinueWith((t) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Job has been completed");
            }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion)
            .ContinueWith((t) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Job has been canceled");
            }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnCanceled)
            .ContinueWith((t) =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Exception thrown: {0}", t.Exception.InnerException);
                }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);

            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Press 'x' to cancel");
                while (Console.ReadKey(true).KeyChar != 'x')
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(200);
                }

                cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
            });

            try
            {
                jobTask.Wait();
            }
            catch (AggregateException ex)
            {
                foreach (var v in ex.InnerExceptions)
                {
                    if (v is TaskCanceledException)
                        Console.WriteLine("Task has been canceled");
                    else
                        Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0} - {1}", v.GetType().Name, v.InnerException);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", ex.Message);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("E - {0}", ex.Message);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to exit");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you press "x" so the `cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();` gets called?

Comment: No, of course I didn't!:) I updated my post so people will know that

Comment: [Task not in a faulted state when an exception is thrown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47726080/7444103).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Task.ContinueWith` method returns a new `Task` object that represents the continuation. If the criteria specified in the `continuationOptions` parameter are not met, then the continuation task is cancelled.

Your code has three calls to `continueWith` chained together. This actually creates four tasks:

- A `Task` for the execution of the delegate passed to `Task.Run` that throws an exception after two seconds
- The first continuation `Task` that runs only if the first `Task` completes successfully
- The second continuation `Task` that runs only if the first continuation is cancelled
- The third continuation `Task` that runs only if the second continuation is faulted

When the exception is thrown, the first `Task` is faulted, the first continuation is cancelled because the `Task` it's continuing didn't complete successfully, the second continuation runs because the first continuation cancelled, and the third continuation is cancelled because the second continuation doesn't fault.

The try block is calling `Wait` on `jobTask`, which holds the `Task` for the third continuation, which is always cancelled.

Microsoft documentation reference: [Task.ContinueWith](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith?view=netframework-4.8#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_ContinueWith_System_Action_System_Threading_Tasks_Task_System_Object__System_Object_System_Threading_CancellationToken_System_Threading_Tasks_TaskContinuationOptions_System_Threading_Tasks_TaskScheduler_)